# Pass a local value to a controller method in Rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code which displays a dropdown menu (I have it this way the so the form shows the last selected option).  I would like to pass the value associated with the selection to a method in my controller.

I want to save this to the the value of "choice" which is specified as an integer in my user model.  The initial value of choice is 0.

I can't seem to find a way to do this with the local "value".

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value= 1>One</option>
    <option value= 2>Two</option>
    <option value= 3>Three</option>
</select>

<%= link_to "Select", {controller: :controller_name, action: :method_name, value: :value} %>
```

Controller method (I am using Devise to call "current_user")

```
def method_name
  current_user.choice = value
  current_user.save
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: You can use form_for containing one select box as you specified above. And add 'post' route for method_name instead of using get request.

Comment: Your `value` is probably contained in `params`: `params[:value]`. My advice for you is to learn some Rails basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms), here is an example of what you need below:

```
<%= form_tag(url_for(controller: 'controller_name', action: 'method_name'), method: :method_type(PUT, POST, etc.)  do %>
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= label_tag(:choice, "Choice") %>
     <%= select_tag(:choice, options_for_select([0, 1, 2, 3], selected: 0)) %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag 'Save'%>
<% end %>
```

As a commenter eluded to, in your method you can then use:

```
def method_name
  current_user.choice = params[:choice]
  current_user.save
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I had played around with form_for, but this is what I was looking for.